# Qualtrics: How do I resize a piped image answer?

Tags: javascript, image, resize, qualtrics

On Qualtrics,
I am trying to pipe and resize one of my image answer to another question.

For example,

Q1: Selected Answer A(a image)

Goal: To Pipe and Resize it to Q2

Q2: ${q://QID2/ChoiceGroup/SelectedChoice}    <---how do I resize it?

Is there any way I can do that?

Thank you and appreciate your help :)

Comment: The Qualtrics server will resolve the piped value into html that will include an `<img>` tag.  Use JavaScript to find the image and modify it's size properties.

Comment: The problem is that it is an answer instead of a pure image, so after I piped it, the value will not include <img> even if I view it in HTML.
It is displayed as <br>${q://QID7/ChoiceGroup/SelectedChoices}<br>, or can still use JavaScript to find the image and modify the size here

Thank you :)

Comment: The Qualtrics server resolves all pipes before sending the page to the browser. So the pipe is replaced by html. There has to be an either an img tag or a background url on another element to display an image in the browser. Right click on the image and choose Inspect.

Comment: I can see the tag in Inspect, how do I resize it? Would it be different if I select another image answer with the same piped?

Comment: Two things: (1) update your post with what you found, and (2) try writing some JavaScript to find img tag and change either the size attributes or the style (whichever it is using). If the images are all the same size, the only difference for a different img would be the img src.

Comment: So in the Inspect of my piped image, I found <img src="https://universityofbrighton.eu.qualtrics.com/WRQualtricsControlPanel/Graphic.php?IM=IM_2aYBJXdrK2vk765&amp;thumb=true&amp;width=300" alt="R3" data-image-state="ready">

I will try write some but not entirely know how(will search it online), where should I put them tho?

Thank you for your help as I am really new with Qualtrics and Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Even though you haven't provide any code, I'll make an exception to get you started...

You add JavaScript by clicking on the cog to the left of the question (the second question in your scenario) and select Add JavaScript. Then replace what is there with this:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
  jQuery("#"+this.questionId+" img").css({"width":"200px","height":"200px"});
});
```

Change 200px to your desired width and height. Assuming there is only one image in the question, the code finds the `<img>` element within the current question `<div>` and adds width and height styles to it.